# UI Testing with respect to a attribute value iOS/Swift

Tags: ios, swift, testing, xcode-ui-testing

I'm writing UI Tests for my application. I've an attribute named `numberOfPhotos` in `PhotosViewController` and it's value is set from another ViewController. Whenever `numberOfPhotos` is 2, only two photos should be displayed in my current `PhotosViewController`.

I was able to test if required number of images are visible or not but I'm not able to set `numberOfPhotos` from UITests class. Is there anyway I can set this value and proceed to tests.

Currents I'm editing the code to set value for `numberOfPhotos` and testing it. Is there anyway I can set this value from UITests class. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

They are different apps, that's why you can't set it directly. The UiTests use a test runner that runs your app. There is a way to do what you want using `launchArguments`.

From your tests:

```
let app = XCUIApplication()
app.launchArguments = XCUIApplication().launchArguments + ["UiTesting", "numberOfPhotos", "2"])
app.launch()
```

From your app:

```
var isUiTesting: Bool {
    return ProcessInfo.processInfo.arguments.contains("UiTesting")
}
```

Write some code in your controller to check the `isUiTesting` property and set the number of photos based on the next few `launchArguments`. You will have to do some parsing of the launch arguments.